# find number of time slots in a datetime column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

My question is relevant my previous question. But, it is different.So I created a new post.

I would like to find how many 10 minutes duration grouped by "id1" in a datetime column in pandas dataframe.

my table:

```
 id1       date_time               adress       a_size        
 reom      2005-8-20 21:51:10      75157.5413   ceifwekd    
 reom      2005-8-20 22:51:10      3571.37946   ceifwekd    
 reom      2005-8-20 11:21:01      3571.37946   tnohcve     
 reom      2005-8-20 11:31:05      97439.219    tnohcve     
 penr      2005-8-20 17:07:16     97439.219    ceifwekd     
 penr      2005-8-20 19:10:37      7391.6258    ceifwekd    
 ....
```

i need

```
 id1       date_time               adress       a_size        10mins_num_by_id1
 reom      2005-8-20 21:51:10      75157.5413   ceifwekd    7
 reom      2005-8-20 21:56:10      3571.37946   ceifwekd    7
 reom      2005-8-20 22:21:01      3571.37946   tnohcve     7
 reom      2005-8-20 22:51:11      97439.219    tnohcve     7
 penr      2005-8-20 17:07:16     97439.219    ceifwekd     2
 penr      2005-8-20 17:17:37      7391.6258    ceifwekd    2
 ....
```

For

```
  id1       date_time               adress       a_size        10mins_num_by_id1
 reom      2005-8-20 21:51:10      75157.5413   ceifwekd    7
 reom      2005-8-20 22:51:11      3571.37946   ceifwekd    7
```

I got 7 because from 21:51:10 to 22:51:11, it has 7 10-mins time slot grouped by "id1"

For

```
 id1       date_time               adress       a_size        10mins_num_by_id1
 penr      2005-8-20 17:07:16     97439.219    ceifwekd     2
 penr      2005-8-20 17:17:37      7391.6258    ceifwekd    2
```

I got 2 because from 17:07:16 to  17:17:37 there are 2 10-minutes time slot grouped by "id1".

My code:

```
 df['10_min'] = df.groupby(['id1']).apply(lambda x: x['date_time'].dt.floor('10Min').count())
```

But I got NaN for the new column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for difference between maximal and minimal `datetime`s, then use [`Series.dt.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) and convert timedeltas to `10Min`s timeslots:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

df['new'] = (df.groupby('id1')['date_time']
               .transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
               .dt.ceil('10Min')
               .dt.total_seconds()
               .div(600)
               .astype(int))
print (df)

    id1           date_time       adress    a_size  new
0  reom 2005-08-20 21:51:10  75157.54130  ceifwekd    7
1  reom 2005-08-20 22:51:10   3571.37946  ceifwekd    7
2  reom 2005-08-20 22:21:01   3571.37946   tnohcve    7
3  reom 2005-08-20 22:51:11  97439.21900   tnohcve    7
4  penr 2005-08-20 17:07:16  97439.21900  ceifwekd    2
5  penr 2005-08-20 17:17:37   7391.62580  ceifwekd    2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `groupby` with `transform` and get `max - min` and then divide by 10 minutes. Finally we use `numpy.ceil` to round up:

```
df['10mins_num_by_id1'] = np.ceil(df.groupby(['id1'])['date_time']\
                                 .transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()) / pd.Timedelta('10 minutes'))

print(df)

print(df)
    id1           date_time       adress    a_size  10mins_num_by_id1
0  reom 2005-08-20 21:51:10  75157.54130  ceifwekd                7.0
1  reom 2005-08-20 22:56:10   3571.37946  ceifwekd                7.0
2  reom 2005-08-20 22:21:01   3571.37946   tnohcve                7.0
3  reom 2005-08-20 22:51:11  97439.21900   tnohcve                7.0
4  penr 2005-08-20 17:07:16  97439.21900  ceifwekd                2.0
5  penr 2005-08-20 17:17:37   7391.62580  ceifwekd                2.0
```